# Using many credentials with sshCommand on remote server in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline which to connect to remote server as below:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'server'
    GIT_CREDENTIAL = 'git'
  }

  stages {
    stage("Connect remote server") {
      steps {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "${SERVER_CREDENTIAL}", usernameVariable: 'username', passwordVariable: 'password']]) {
          script {
          def remote = [:]
          remote.name = "server"
          remote.host = "x.x.x.x"
          remote.allowAnyHosts = true
          remote.user = "$username"
          remote.password = "$password"

          sshCommand remote: remote, command: "cd /www && git fetch"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can connect to server but git denied permission because there is no ssh key on that server. I don't want to store sshkey as well. Is there way to run a **git fetch** with my Jenkins git credentials.
Tried to research but nothing help.

I also tried this but not working

```
sshagent(["$GIT_CREDENTIAL"]) {
  withCredentials(...) {
    remote.agentForwading = true
    sshCommand ...
  }
}
```

By the way, can I break commands in separate code lines which keep previous state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself with this way.

```
steps {
  sshagent(["$GIT_CREDENTIAL"]) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "$SERVER_CREDENTIAL", passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
      script {
        COMMANDS = "cd /www && git fetch"
        sh "sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $USERNAME@$SERVER '$COMMANDS'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am still not sure why SSH Pipeline Steps plugin not forwarding ssh key. From link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55241, this guy says it is using different library. So, I used other solution with sshpass.

Hope this help other people.